# Personalização de hiperlink no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Alguem sabe se tem algum modo que eu possa criar um hiperlink em uma célula no excel onde o valor especificado nesta célula seja passada para o valor de id de uma URL? Exemplo:

Célula com valor: 100531, ao clicar em cima ela chame uma url http://teste/teste/view.php?id=VALORDACELULA onde o VALORDACELULA seja o valor que esteja na celula que  foi clicada?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você vai criar os hyperlinks nas células um a um?

Comment: Pode ser, desde que pegue o valor da célula, nesse caso eu posso fazer uma vez e arrastar pra baixo que aplicará em todos os outros

Comment: Preparei uma resposta então. Mas talvez seja mais fácil você criar os hyperlinks por sua própria conta, utilizando VBA também. Dá uma olhada em [`Hyperlinks.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff822490.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Na célula onde está o valor, clique com o botão direito do mouse e selecione "Hyperlink".
2. Na janela de hyperlinks, selecione o botão "Colocar Neste Documento" e digite o endereço da própria célula onde está o valor. Clique OK. Este hyperlink não fará nada pois ele leva para a própria célula onde foi clicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Abra a janela de código VBA do Excel (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) e adicione o seguinte código à planilha:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal oTarget As Hyperlink)
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "http://teste/teste/view.php?id=" & ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sURL
End Sub
```

> Observe que esse código captura o evento **da planilha específica** (a
>   *worksheet*, isto é, a aba) e não do arquivo todo. Se você tiver mais de uma
>   aba (Plan1, Plan2, Plan3, etc) e quiser fazer o mesmo nela, precisará duplicar
>   esse código.

Comment: Ele não está pegando o valor e sim a posição, quando clico vai para id=Plan1!E2

Comment: Porque você não configurou o link para ir na planilha certa (veja a imagem do item 2) e, principalmente, não colocou o código na planilha certa (veja o comentário no final da resposta que eu acabei de editar).

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quis dizer: eu não postei imagem alguma de url inexistente. Vc colocou a referência E2, **mas de qual planilha?** Se ele foi pra PEDIDOS!E2 e não era pra ir, é porque você colocou E2 da planilha errada.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como na imagem, coloquei em referencia da celula a posicao E2. Nao tenho mais de uma aba, até a renomeei para pedidos, ainda assim clico a vai para PEDIDOS!E2

Comment: Mas a célula onde vc colocou o link está na E2?

Comment: Aliás, o que você quer dizer com "vai"? O Excel, ou a URL? Porque eu não sei se você notou, mas eu fiz uma correção no código pra pegar o valor da célula e não o nome do link. Foi bem no comecinho, talvez vc pegou a versão anterior do código?

Comment: Me desculpa nao tinha notado, é extamente isso, funcionou :) obrigado.

Comment: Por nada. Mas veja que demorou mais pra eu entender o que você tava falando do que pra fazer o exemplo. rs Não leve a mal o comentário, mas no futuro procure ser mais claro nas explicações. "Ele vai" ou "ele não está pegando" são expressões muito vagas.

Comment: certo, me atentarei a isso, só uma dúvida, tem como no momento que eu digitar o valor na celula, ja setar o valor respectivo a ela na url, ou terei que fazer o procedimento 2 para cada célula manualmente ?

Comment: Não tem como. Foi por isso que [a minha primeira pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148472/personaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-hiperlink-no-excel/148482?noredirect=1#comment306539_148472) pra você foi se você iria criar os links manualmente, e você respondeu que sim. Você até pode fazer um outro procedimento (em um botão, por exemplo) que cria os hyperlinks manualmente, mas seria para os valores que já estão nas células. Se quiser algo mais rebuscado, vai precisar implementar um formulário para o usuário digitar fora da célula.

Comment: De todas as formas, este site não é um fórum. Se tiver mais dúvidas, abra outra pergunta. E se for abrir outra pergunta sobre o mesmo "assunto", sugiro não fornecer uma solução parcial sua e pedir para alguém ajudá-la a torná-la correta, mas explicar o problema e deixar a comunidade oferecer uma solução adequada (isto é, explique do que se trata a sua planilha, quem são os usuários, se eles vão digitar os valores e querem automaticamente ir para os links em cada um, ou dá pra fazer isso de uma forma centralizada (uma janela que o usuário clique e selecione a célula para então ir para o site)?